# How to make different navbar for different pages react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header, navbar

This is my App.js but i want to make a different navbar for admin and client part. ...............
I Have  and  but i want to shitch for a client , and dashboard. ................
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';
import Footer from './components/Layouts/Footer/Footer';
import Header from './components/Layouts/Header/Header';
import Navbar from './components/Layouts/Header/Navbar';
import Login from './components/User/Login';
import Register from './components/User/Register';
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { loadUser } from './actions/userAction';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import UpdateProfile from './components/User/UpdateProfile';
import UpdatePassword from './components/User/UpdatePassword';
import ForgotPassword from './components/User/ForgotPassword';
import ResetPassword from './components/User/ResetPassword';
import Account from './components/User/Account';
import ProtectedRoute from './Routes/ProtectedRoute';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import ProductDetails from './components/ProductDetails/ProductDetails';
import Products from './components/Products/Products';
import Cart from './components/Cart/Cart';
import Shipping from './components/Cart/Shipping';
import OrderConfirm from './components/Cart/OrderConfirm';
import Payment from './components/Cart/Payment';
import OrderStatus from './components/Cart/OrderStatus';
import OrderSuccess from './components/Cart/OrderSuccess';
import MyOrders from './components/Order/MyOrders';
import OrderDetails from './components/Order/OrderDetails';
import Dashboard from './components/Admin/Dashboard';
import MainData from './components/Admin/MainData';
import OrderTable from './components/Admin/OrderTable';
import UpdateOrder from './components/Admin/UpdateOrder';
import ProductTable from './components/Admin/ProductTable';
import CategoryTable from './components/Admin/CategoryTable';
import NewProduct from './components/Admin/NewProduct';
import NewCategory from './components/Admin/NewCategory';
import UpdateProduct from './components/Admin/UpdateProduct';
import UpdateCategory from './components/Admin/UpdateCategory';
import UserTable from './components/Admin/UserTable';
import UpdateUser from './components/Admin/UpdateUser';
import ReviewsTable from './components/Admin/ReviewsTable';
import Wishlist from './components/Wishlist/Wishlist';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';
import { DataProvider } from './store'
import Categories from './components/Categories';



function App() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Roboto:300,400,500,600,700"]
      },
    });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser());
    // getStripeApiKey();
  }, [dispatch]);



  // always scroll to top on route/path change
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }, [pathname])

  // disable right click
  // window.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => e.preventDefault());
  // window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  //   if (e.keyCode == 123) e.preventDefault();
  //   if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 73) e.preventDefault();
  //   if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 74) e.preventDefault();
  // });

  return (
    <>
    <Header />
      <DataProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
          <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
          <Route path="/products/:keyword" element={<Products />} />
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
          {/* <Route path="/category" element={<Categories />} /> */}
          {/* order process */}
          <Route path="/shipping" element={<ProtectedRoute><Shipping /></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/order/confirm" element={<ProtectedRoute><OrderConfirm /></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/process/payment" element={<ProtectedRoute> <Payment /> </ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/orders/success" element={<OrderSuccess success={true} />} />
          <Route path="/orders/failed" element={<OrderSuccess success={false} />} />
          {/* order process */}
          <Route path="/order/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute><OrderStatus /></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/orders" element={<ProtectedRoute> <MyOrders /> </ProtectedRoute>}></Route>
          <Route path="/order_details/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute><OrderDetails /></ProtectedRoute>}></Route>
          <Route path="/account" element={<ProtectedRoute><Account /></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/account/update" element={<ProtectedRoute><UpdateProfile /></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/password/update" element={<ProtectedRoute><UpdatePassword /></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/password/forgot" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
          <Route path="/password/reset/:token" element={<ResetPassword />} />
          <Route path="/wishlist" element={<ProtectedRoute><Wishlist /></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/dashboard" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={0}><MainData /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/orders" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={1}><OrderTable /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/order/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={1}><UpdateOrder /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/products" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={2}><ProductTable /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/category" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={6}><CategoryTable /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/new_product" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={3}><NewProduct /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/new_category" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={6}><NewCategory /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/product/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={2}><UpdateProduct /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/category/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={6}><UpdateCategory /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/users" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={4}><UserTable /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/user/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={4}><UpdateUser /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/admin/reviews" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}><Dashboard activeTab={5}><ReviewsTable /></Dashboard></ProtectedRoute>} ></Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </DataProvider>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

how to define the expression

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods you can use here.

1. You change your header component so it can render itself differently. In your case, I suppose you will not need any major changes. You are using redux, so you can use the user state inside the header to make changes accordingly. Or, you could also use the current URL and make changes accordingly.
2. The other method is to make different components and pass them inside the `Route` tag.

```
<Route 
    path="/admin/user/:id" 
    element={
        <ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true}>
            <AdminHeader />
            <Dashboard activeTab={4}>
                <UpdateUser />
            </Dashboard>
        </ProtectedRoute>
     }
></Route>
```

Comment: The second method is easier for me. But when I do it as explained the two navbars overlap.
Can you explain to me in detail for my variant how it should be done?

Comment: They overlap because you are still using the `<Header/>` tag above. Remove that. You now have to individually add `<Header/>` or `<AdminHeader/>` inside each route.